# Mandrill message not registered but status is sent

Tags: php, api, mandrill

I am trying to send an email using Mandrill API using "messages/send-template" request
in return I receive the following response:

```
[
    {
        email: "test@email.com",
        status: "sent",
        _id: "8ff773d1c683434891cee94e461e53e7",
        reject_reason: null
    }
]
```

but when i try to execute "messages/info" request I get an error

```
Mandrill_Unknown_Message: No message exists with the id '8ff773d1c683434891cee94e461e53e7'
```

I use the following code for those actions:

```
$message_data = array(
    'text'  => '123',
    'from_email'  => 'sender@email.com',
    'to' => array(
        array('email' => 'test@email.com')
    ),
);

try {
    $md_message = $this->_mandrill->messages->send($message_data);

    foreach($md_message as $message) {

        if($message['status'] != 'sent') {
            trigger_error("Internal Error (Mandrill): ".$message['reject_reason']);
            return false;
        }

        $info = $this->_mandrill->messages->info($message['_id']);
    }

    return true;

} catch (Exception $m) {
    trigger_error("Internal Error (Mandrill): ".$m->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Also the message doesn't appear in the control panel at Mandrill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, Looks like test API key won't get any messages recorded.
I created a new API key (not test) - and it worked =]

Cheers